# hover effect on div whilst hover over whole a tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ok I am trying to get a hover effect on my div *(   `<div class="thumbnail-green-test">`)* I can do this simply *(code bellow)*

What I need though is the div *(   `<div class="thumbnail-green-test">`)*  to have the hover effect if use hovers over the *`H3`* as well as the div but only the effect showing on the *`div`*.

***partially working***

**html**

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="thumbnail-green-test">
                    here be image
                </div>
                <h3 class="">test</h3>
            </a>
        </div>
```

**css**

```
.thumbnail-green-test:hover {
    border: 10px solid hotpink !important;
}
```

***what I have tried***

This dose not give me what i want at it gives the effect to the whole area, i only want the border on the `*div with "image be here"*` but to appear if you hover over the whole section.

**html**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail-green-test">
            <a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="">
                    here be image
                </div>
                <h3 class="">test</h3>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle

Comment: yeah sure, 4 mins

Comment: can the markup be changed ? or do we have restrictions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
div.col-md-3:hover .thumbnail-green-test {
  border: 10px solid hotpink !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">
    <div class="thumbnail-green-test">
      here be image
    </div>
    <h3 class="">test</h3>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, 6 mins till I can accept

Comment: what about explanation?

Comment: @dippas it is a regular CSS. no magic

Comment: I agree, was a simple problem to solve i just could not work it out this morning. thanks @Andy

Comment: no magic for you, but OP had issues, so should had some explanation as minimum it was, not just dumping code

Comment: @dippas It is a simple css selector change that explains itself with the provided code. No need to over-explain. Anyone not understanding a basic change such as that has bigger problems I would think.

Comment: @dippas styles apply only to the last item in the selector. On the other hand pseudo `:hover` does not have to be the end, and can be applied to any parent element, by pointing to which we want to change the target element styles. Excuse my English is not a native.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov I understand perfectly the code, but what I meant was the explanation should be there for the OP and future readers. not for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using only `css`

```
.col-md-3:hover .thumbnail-green-test {
   border: 10px solid hotpink !important;
}
```

Or using `jquery`

```js
$('.col-md-3').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.thumbnail-green-test').css({"border-color": "hotpink", 
             "border-width":"10px", 
             "border-style":"solid"});
});
$('.col-md-3').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.thumbnail-green-test').removeAttr( 'style' );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="thumbnail-green-test">
                    here be image
                </div>
                <h3 class="">test</h3>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: This does not seem to work at all ► http://jsfiddle.net/y6nf0d7s/

Comment: @Fran, your fiddle is wrong.

Comment: Nope it is using your exact css! - The reason your selector `.thumbnail-green-test div:hover{` doesn't work is because it is looking for a `div` **inside** an element with class `.thumbnail-green-test` which doesn't exist. Hence your code doesn't work. There is no `div` inside as the `div` itself has the class.

Comment: plus 1 for the jquery but I amgoing with the answer from Andy works well

Comment: @BenjaminOats The JQuery specified in the answer `$('.thumbnail-green-test').find('div').css('border','10px solid hotpink !important;');` is wrong as it looks for a `div` inside `.thumbnail-green-test` which is not your markup. At least this answer has now updated the CSS to match the other correct answer so there is that I guess :)

Comment: I updated answer with jquery version. Firstly,I am looking wrong at HTML in your post.